# HTML5 Audios in different pages are playing independently

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, audio, mobile

I have two pages in my ionic mobile project.
Each page has html5 audio controls.
When I play audio in first page, I can navigate other apps without stopping music which is good.
And if I play any types of audio from other app, it will stop my audio in my first page which is also good.
The problem is that when I play audio in first page while I am playing audio in second page both audios are playing.
How can I stop or pause previous audio in other page when i play audio in different page?

Comment: How are your components set up?
You can use Input() and Output to have components communicate with each other.
[https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to this:

1. Stop the audio in the first page when opening the second page
2. Make yourself an audio service:

`@Injectable()
export class AudioService {
    audio;

   setAudioFromUrl(url: string){
     this.pause();
     this.audio = new Audio(url)
   }

  pause(){
    if(this.audio)
      this.audio.pause()

  }
}`

Usage: Add the service to module providers. Inject it to the components that use it. set the file you want to play using this service in each component

Comment: For more information on services see this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4